# How to hide url in Address bar

Tags: html

I want to keep same url for all the pages of my site.

ex: if my site is www.abc.com & xyz.html is a page.

I want to display www.abc.com or www.abc.com/xyz instead of www.abc.com/xyz.htm

Please help me to do this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use `.htaccess` see link to know how to use it (focus on rewrite rule): http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript for that , for example

```
 <script>
   var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
   history.pushState(stateObj, "page without extension", "xyz");
 </script>
```

You can read more about here :

[Explanation](https://rosspenman.com/pushstate-jquery/)

Or use a PHP Routing system, theres a lot of information about it in google

Answer (score -1):

Use this snippets in your  .htaccess file

Now you can use this in Url abc.com/xyz and it redirect you to abc.com/xyz.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]    {1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```